# Is there any reason to use different routers with the same prefix?

Tags: fastapi

I am wondering if there is a reason to use routers in fastAPI is the prfeix is the same between both routers. Let's say I have 2 different routers with /api/v1 as a prefix:

**app.py**

```
from src.api.v1.auth import auth_router
from src.api.v1.admin import admin_router

    def create_app() -> FastAPI:
        root_app = FastAPI()
        root_app.include_router(
            auth_router,
            prefix="/api/v1",
            tags=["auth"],
        )
        root_app.include_router(
            admin_router,
            prefix="/api/v1",
            tags=["admin"],
        )
```

**auth.py**

```
auth_router = auth = APIRouter()


@auth.get("/")
def hello():
  return {'hello world from router'}
```

**admin.py**

```
admin_router = admin = APIRouter()


@admin.get("/")
def hello():
  return {'hello world from admin'}
```

If I am going to my app swagger, the url to access both endpoint is exactly the same: `localhost:8000/api/v1`

So is there a reason to not use different prefix in routers?

Comment: I'm guessing just one of your routers will be called when they're both mounted in the same location and have the same route?

Comment: your postfix need to be different names admin auth ... must be prefix/admin and prefix/auth and ...